# configure library function node parameter for an array of strings

Tags: c, labview

How to configure the library function node parameter in LabView for a C function declared like this:

```
char listPorts(cust_struct *cust, unsigned char *pPort, char (*pSer)[16])
```

I don't know how to configure the parameter `char (*pSer)[16]`. I've tried it as Type `Adapt to Type`(with a cluster consisting of strings). But this will raise `Error 1097`.

This pointer will write strings to an array. How do I have to configure this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism in LabVIEW to directly pass a LabVIEW array of strings to a C-style array of strings parameter, particularly not one with fixed size. You will need to write a wrapper DLL around that function that can translate the LabVIEW data structure into a C data structure (or vice versa), managing the memory transformation along the way.

This document will help you understand the memory layout.

[Using Arrays and Strings in the Call Library Function Node](http://zone.ni.com/reference/zhs-XX/help/371361R-0118/lvexcodeconcepts/array_and_string_options/)